# Strange underline symbols in vim

Tags: vim, symbols, underline

Could you please tell me what does the underline symbols in the picture mean (they are not there in insert mode, when I write something to that place it will get underlined) and how to get rid of them?

[image]

thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is vim drawing underlines on the place of tabs and how to avoid this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625274/why-is-vim-drawing-underlines-on-the-place-of-tabs-and-how-to-avoid-this)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, vim is underlining tab characters. This (answered) question may help you: [Why is vim drawing underlines on the place of tabs and how to avoid this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625274/why-is-vim-drawing-underlines-on-the-place-of-tabs-and-how-to-avoid-this)

Comment: Thank you. I haven't noticed that this question was already asked. But what does this sentence mean? "This setting will, however, also disable bold and italic styling for html files." It's related to **gvim**?

Comment: @xralf It seems that the let html_no_rendering=1 option mentioned in the other question disables special syntax highlighting that is specific to HTML files, including underlining tabs but also some other formatting (I'm afraid I don't know which). I think you could just replace the tab characters with spaces to remove the underlining if you don't wish to lose that other formatting, but I can see how that would be an issue for a large page, so I would recommend setting the option as described in the other question and see if it works out for you or not.

Comment: @xralf It is related to any vim: some terminals do support italic and almost all terminals support bold font styles.

Comment: For clarification vim is not underlining tabs, it is underlining everything between `<a>` tags.