# VIM: Don't underline leading whitespace in HTML links

Tags: vim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is vim drawing underlines on the place of tabs and how to avoid this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625274/why-is-vim-drawing-underlines-on-the-place-of-tabs-and-how-to-avoid-this)

When indenting PHP code in VIM 7.0 on CentOS 5.x, HTML links are shown underlined. This is very handy, but in some places I have indented PHP code in that HTML, and the whole indentation is underlined:

```
            <li class="picture">
________________<a href="<?=$linkUrl?>">
____________________<img src="/<?=$img['source']?>" alt="Picture"/>
____________________<? if ($someCondition): ?><span class="info"><?=$img['info']?></span><? endif; ?>
________________</a>
            </li>
```

Is there any way to tell the syntax highlighter to ignore line-leading whitespace in HTML links?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I managed to achieve this through modifying `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/html.vim`. Make a copy to `~/.vim/syntax/html.vim` (`.vim` is named `vimfiles` on Windows), and replace the original syntax definition

```
syn region htmlLink start="<a\>\_[^>]*\<href\>" end="</a>"me=e-4 contains=@Spell,htmlTag,htmlEndTag,htmlSpecialChar,htmlPreProc,htmlComment,javaScript,@htmlPreproc
```

with the following:

```
syn region htmlLink start="<a\>\_[^>]*\<href\>" end="</a>"me=e-4 keepend contains=@Spell,htmlTag,htmlEndTag,htmlSpecialChar,htmlPreProc,htmlComment,htmlLinkText,javaScript,@htmlPreproc
syn match htmlLinkText contained contains=@Spell,htmlTag,htmlEndTag,htmlSpecialChar,htmlPreProc,htmlComment,htmlLinkText,javaScript,@htmlPreproc "^\s*\zs.\{-}\ze\s*$"
syn match htmlLinkText contained contains=@Spell,htmlTag,htmlEndTag,htmlSpecialChar,htmlPreProc,htmlComment,htmlLinkText,javaScript,@htmlPreproc "\S.\{-}\ze\s*$"
```

Further down, change

```
HtmlHiLink htmlLink                    Underlined
```

to

```
HtmlHiLink htmlLinkText                Underlined
```

Voila! Basically, this introduces another contained syntax group `htmlLinkText`, which does not match leading and trailing whitespace, and applies the highlighting to that instead.

Comment: Thank you. For some reason, now none of the links are highlighted but H2 and P tags are highlighted! I went over the changes carefully, I can't seem to find them. The edits are around lines 150 and 253 [if you would like to take a look](http://pastebin.com/kDPAH7g7). Thank you Ingo!

Comment: Your edits are fine, and your file works for me. Do you have any othe definitions, maybe in an ~/.vim/after/syntax/ file?

Comment: No, no other files or definitions, I even tried with a blank ~/.vimrc (so no other system-wide .vimrc would get in the way). This is in a Cygwin terminal SSHing into a CentOS 5.x box, VIM 7.0.

Comment: @dotancohen: I think I've now encounted what you referred to as "H2 and P tags are highlighted now". This can be fixed by adding "keepend" to the htmlLink definition; I've updated my answer.

Comment: Ingo, thank you, that does exactly the trick! This will reduce a real eyesore for me, thanks. I took a look at your site, and I though that you might like to know that Hannah means "beautiful" in Hebrew too.

Comment: I added a bounty for your diligence, but I can only award it in another 24 hours.

Comment: @dotancohen: I appreciate this; glad that it's now working for you, too! I will send this patch to the maintainer of syntax/html.vim, so that maybe this gets into the main distribution.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this:

```
:hi link htmlLink NONE
```

Comment: Thanks, but that disables all link highlights, which I happen to find useful. I am looking to disable the highlight only on line-leading whitespace.