# How do I stop vim from drawing horizontal lines in indentation/leading whitespace?

Tags: vim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [VIM: Don't underline leading whitespace in HTML links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150659/vim-dont-underline-leading-whitespace-in-html-links)

Some of my lines in vim are getting weird horizontal lines in the leading whitespace. I don't know why. Maybe a plugin I have installed?

Here's a picture

[image]

Only some lines get them. I've tried closing and opening the file.

Does anyone know how to turn this off?

Comment: Well... which plugins have you installed?

Comment: That is probably because the contents of an HTML anchor are colorized.  Not sure how to turn it off but you can probably tinker with the HTML syntax file.

Comment: @kev You are correct, this is a duplicated. I have voted to close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those lines are part of the underline syntax highlighting of hyperlinks. Notice that they occur inside `<a>` tags. Some colorschemes  won't underline hyperlinked content inside `<a>`, but if you wanted to continue using the same colorscheme you would need to modify or override the `HtmlHiLink` directives in the `html.vim` syntax files.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer led me to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10150659/817630) which is a duplicate of mine. Feel free to vote to close this question as such.

Comment: @root45 Indeed and it has better answers than mine. I cv'd -- cheers.