# gvim: continuous lines at the beginning of the lines

Tags: vim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is vim drawing underlines on the place of tabs and how to avoid this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625274/why-is-vim-drawing-underlines-on-the-place-of-tabs-and-how-to-avoid-this)

Im getting continuous line when I write spaces or tabs at the beginning of the lines:

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/68r69

Any idea?

Javi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't the result of using tabs at the beginning of a line, it's just vim's code-highlighting.

Vim underlines links, and you're still within the body of an <a> tag.It's nothing to worry about, it just shows where the content of the displayable part of the link starts and ends.

You could disable syntax highlighting for HTML, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

The text inside a HTML hyperlink in underlined by Vim's syntax highlighting to show that it is a link. In this case the whitespace surrounding the  tag is being highlighted.

Switching off such underlining is addressed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625274/why-is-vim-drawing-underlines-on-the-place-of-tabs-and-how-to-avoid-this) and boils down to setting

```
:let html_no_rendering=1
```

which you could put in your .vimrc.

Answer (score 0):

It's a flaw in the syntax definition; I've posted a fix [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10165836/813602); I'll send this as a patch to the maintainer now, as it seems to be a constant source of confusion.